# Switch a whole application to alternative "styles.xml" files at run time?

Tags: android

my app has a `styles.xml` file with various visual constants defined.

I'd like my users to be able to switch the entire app to an alternative visual theme. I'd like to provide an alternative `styles2.xml` file and switch at runtime (via the Settings).

Is this possible, and how? I suspect the style names' appearance in the generated R class does not bode well.

If it's not possible, what's my next best option?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but i'm interested in the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anyone is still interested but I have found a possible solution. A bit hackish but gets the desired result.
Basically I set up my 2 style files in separate country code directories:

```
res/values-mcc199/style.xml
res/values-mcc198/style.xml
```

Then in my activity I use the following to change which is referenced:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.mcc = 199;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,null);
```

I've only done some basic testing so far but it appears to work. Obviously if you are already using country code to decide your layouts then this will interfere. I think there may be problems as well if the phone gets an event about a country change.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after some reading of the doc, it seems that this can be done. [Look here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)
As it is mentionned :

> To create a set of styles, save an XML
> file in the res/values/ directory of
> your project. The name of the XML file
> is arbitrary, but it must use the .xml
> extension and be saved in the
> res/values/  folder.

Now, if this is logical and I didn't read the doc wrongly, you can create as many styles as you want, reference them in themes.xml with @style/... (if you want to apply it to a whole activity or application) and then, just call

> setTheme(R.id.yourtheme)

I think this should work. Have a go at it and tell us?

Comment: Looks promising Sephy I'll give it a go.

Comment: I believe this only works before the activity content is loaded. After that it appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer; in my blog post here:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/switching-android-configurations-using-constants-and-ant/

I switch out a java class at build time using Ant, there is nothing to stop you switching out an XML file, as it compiles **after** the switch. To amend the tutorial you'd just have to change the path's of the file your templating.

Also mirrored on GitHub: https://github.com/blundell/BuildChoiceTut